# Silverlight 3/4 Navigation Application - Access child page controls from Parent page

Tags: silverlight

How can I access child page controls from the parent page in a Silverlight 3/4 Navigation Application? I wish to hide an image from the child page when I click a button in the parent page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by returning a reference to the child page to the parent page when the navigation frame's Navigated event completes.  The NavigationEventArgs parameter has a "Content" property which is set to the child page which has just been navigated to.